# select checkbox and display pats of form accordingly

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

[image: have the code for two checkboxes but how can I do it for 3?].Like for two checkboxes there is true or false but what should I do for 3 checkoxes ?to display parts of form according to the checkbox selection.

Comment: Exactly how did you do this for two?

Comment: please refer to the image.

Comment: Pictures of code are difficult to read and tedious to copy to answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of multiple values (by setting distinct values in the `value="…"` argument, and update the conditions in the `ng-show="…"` argument accordingly, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="modelname" value="1">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="modelname" value="2">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="modelname" value="3">3</input>

<div ng-show="modelname=='1'">form1</div>
<div ng-show="modelname=='2'">form2</div>
<div ng-show="modelname=='3'">form3</div>
```

Comment: how do I submit only one part as when Iam submitting the form I'am unable to unless all of the three forms are filled .I just want to select one the checkboxes and submit that particular form while the rest are unchecked they do not need to be filled.Here I have asked a question regarding my problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/60371247/12933067

Answer (score 0):

Set value from the input checkbox using "value=", and change the conditions in the ng-if="…" argument accordingly, as shown below:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="variable" value=1>your content</input>
<input type="radio" ng-model="variable" value=2>your content</input>
<input type="radio" ng-model="variable" value=3>your content</input>

<div ng-if="variable==1">your form</div>
<div ng-if="variable==2">your form</div>
<div ng-if="variable==3">your form</div>
```